# Script to push recently changed files from one (dev) server to remote (live) server?

Tags: linux, push, live

I haven't been able to find a specific answer on this in my Googling, so I figure maybe someone has an answer for me or can point me in the right direction.

I have 2 servers both running CentOS 6.3.  One is a dev server and the other is the live server.  I make all changes on the dev server, test them out, and then copy them to the live server once I'm satisfied.  The system works fine, but it's a pain to have to use scp or rsync everytime and type the entire absolute dir paths every time I push a file or dir.

I'm not an experienced sysadmin by any means, but I would love a way to just run one script that will take all recently changed files (maybe in the last 20 minutes, or a time that I specify) and have it automatically push them to the live server, maintaining the same directory structure and everything.

Is there something easy out there that will do this for me, or some kind of bash script I can write to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe rsync can do this. Just wrap rsync in a simple shell script.

Comment: Awesome suggestion Keith. I looked a little more into rsync and found the --update command that will only send files that are newer than the versions on the remote server, so I didn't even need to write a script for it, I just created an alias that will sync those directories everytime I run it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
find -mmin -20 -exec mv {} {}NEW \;
```

`find -mmin -20` finds all files that were last modified less than 20 minutes ago. You can also specify a directory.

The `-exec` option invokes a command on all the found files. `{}` is replaced with the actual filename. In my example the files are simply renamed, the executed command would be

```
mv filename filenameNEW
```

for every file. Here you'd put your `scp` or `rsync` statement of course.

The `-exec` command needs to end with a `;`, since `;` is also a special character in bash, it needs to be escaped with `\`

Comment: That's good to know, I honestly didn't even know about the -mmin command.  Ok so that will help me actually find all the files that I've recently changed, now can I execute this in a bash script that will loop through all the files, run scp on them and copy them to the exact same directory on my remote server?

Comment: Yes, just replace the `mv` command with your `scp` command. You don't need to take care of the loop over the files in bash, `find -exec` will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out, thanks to the help I had from Keith and pfnuesel.  Here's my solution in case anyone else is looking for an easy way to do this.

I ended up using the --update option in rsync, which will essentially only copy files over to the remote server that are newer than the version that exists there.  So I ended up just creating a function in my ~/.bashrc file that will run it for me.  Here's my function I threw together-

```
function push() {
    rsync -avzu /var/www/$1 root@12.34.56.78:/var/www/$1
}
```

So I can just run "push dirname" and it works like a charm.  Thanks for the help guys!